# How to lower the RPM of a motor without using PWM or gears?

Tags: motor, pwm, dc-motor, resistance, rpm

I need to lower the RPM of a simple DC motor to almost 20 - 30 RPM for some reasons. I cannot use PWM signals or gears to lower the RPM of the motor (I know how to use them but I want a simple solution.)

Is there any other way that I could slow down this motor? I tried to lower the voltage going to the motor using resistors but it didn't work (for me at least, I connected the resistor between the motor's one wire and the positive terminal of the battery supplying 3 volts. Let me know if I did something wrong.)

I don't care about torque that much so it's not a problem if I lose some torque in the process.

Hoping for a trick that could slow down this motor without using PWM or gears.

Comment: A correctly sized resistor will indeed do it, albeit by wasting power.  You can get an idea of how big a resistor you need by measuring the current the motor draws at 3V.  If the resistor drops too much voltage the motor will be unable to start.  Trying to get such a low RPM is unlikely without a specially designed motor.  20 RPM is very very slow for a small motor, so for most 3v motors, you will basically have no torque left at all at that speed.  With a resistor you can probably get down to half the motor's rated speed, and with PWM maybe 10 or 20%.

Comment: The gears and PWM are the cheapest simplest options unless you're willing to accept 50% speed as minimum RPM for your motor.

Comment: A gearbox IS simple; it's a no-brainer. On the other hand, a control loop with speed feedback to avoid the problems of intermittent cogging torque at low speeds seems much more complex i.e. not simple.

Comment: timing belt, with reduction ... even easier than gears

Comment: @PeteW, what speed would a DC motor run at? OP didn't say. Even if it was only 1000 RPM that would be 50:1 reduction.

Comment: @Transistor -- ok fair point. it would be 2 stages ~7:1, 2 dimensional design - just flat plates, vs a worm gear? or purchased gearbox which may or may not be cheating.

Comment: @Andyaka Ehhhhhh...depends on how you look at it. Sure a gearbox is a no brainer if you can easily get a gearbox. But in practice, if the motor does not already come with a gearbox, finding one to fit it is neither simple nor cheap and is often one of the most expensive (albeit most compact, most efficient, and most effective) ways to go about it. From what I've seen, if you already have the motor and it doesn't come with a gearbox you won't be able to find one, and if you can you'll probably have to pay through the nose for it. Unless you buy gears and DIY which few are equipped to do.

Comment: It is very easy. You just need to supply the motor with a lower voltage. For example if the motor is rated for 1200 RPM at 100V, just supply it with 2.5V to get 30 RPM. With such a drastic reduction there is some danger that it won't spin at all. Also, the power output of the motor will be reduced proportionally. A motor rated for 100 Watts at 100Volts will only deliver 2.5Watts at 2.5Volts. It seems rather unlikely that this will be satisfactory.

Comment: 20 RPM is stepper-motor slow. I don't think you will be able to slow a simple DC 3V motor to that RPM. 120 RPM is crawling slow for a motor with a design of 800 RPM -- and that's with PWM with a pulse frequency above 20KHz to put the audible motor squeal above the human hearing range. What motor do you have. Link to the datasheet?

Comment: A brushed DC motor has a lower limit to the speed at which it will run, determined largely by the number of poles and the commutation of the brushes. A DC motor (and all motors, actually) are AC devices which require a rotating magnetic field. So, yes, this might only be possible with a stepper motor, and probably a micro-stepping controller.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of DC motors depends on voltage, the current is proportional to the torque. If your mechanical load is very low, you will have low current, and the voltage drop in a resistor will be also low, so no change in speed. You can try with diodes, if the current is not very low, you will get moreless 0.5 volts with each one.
Other trial should be to use a resistor voltage divider.
Any how the speed control will be very poor.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a series resistor or PWM you can try a switching buck regulator module such as one based on the XL4016. That will retain the inherent speed regulation of the motor. They are inexpensive and can handle a few amperes.

Internally, it's actually PWM with smoothing afterward, so the motor just sees a reduced DC voltage, which causes it to run more slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Motors are like capacitors,  you can't use a single resistor to reduce the voltage on a capacitor, likewise a single resistor won't work well to reduce the voltage to a motor.

you could use two resistors to make a divider and have more success slowing the motor. the resistors will make lots of heat, but maybe you can use the heat for something.

getting less than 100RPM from a PMDC motor will be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

20 RPM is just 3 seconds per revolution. One possibility would be a series of DC pulses, each of which has enough energy to overcome stall torque, and long enough to turn the rotor some fraction of a revolution. So 200 pulses per minute, each sufficient to provide 36 degrees of rotation, might work. It would also probably require a dynamic brake to keep the inertia from rotating too far. This would best be accomplished with something like a 555 timer, and maybe a half-bridge or SPDT relay to actually drive the armature. It might also be helpful to use a charged capacitor to discharge a pulse into the motor with the right amount of energy to overcome starting torque and limit the ON time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYlcmg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

[image: Motor Current]

Answer (score 0):

The speed of  DC motor is roughly voltage-proportional, so...

[image: schematic]
This will provide an adjustable voltage, and the motor (at zero
torque load) will have a back-EMF roughly equal to the forward
voltage imposed, in proportion to its speed.
The reason a simple resistor does not do the same thing, is that the motor is not a resistive load,so a resistor in series does not
make a constant voltage drop.

That Q1 darlington will probably require a heatsink.